# Writing Numpy Array with NaNs into CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, nan

I am trying to write 2D `numpy array` into csv file using `np.savetxt`.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0,np.nan,2,3],[4,5,np.nan,7],[8,9,10,np.nan]])

np.savetxt("file.csv", data, delimiter=",", fmt='%.2f')
```

Which creates a file `file.csv` with the following content.

```
0.00,nan,2.00,3.00
4.00,5.00,nan,7.00
8.00,9.00,10.00,nan
```

As you can see the file contains `nan` instead of blanks. I know nan is not a string.

**Expected Output:**

```
0.00,,2.00,3.00
4.00,5.00,,7.00
8.00,9.00,10.00,
```

Using `pandas` I can achieve this like below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("file1.csv", index=False)
```

But I'm refraining from using `pandas` for now. So is it possible to achieve this using `numpy`?

Comment: All `savetxt` is doing is a formatted write of each row of your array.  `'%.2f,%.2f,...'%tuple(row)`. Just basic python % formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward solution:

```
data1 = data.astype(str)
data1[data1=='nan'] = ''
np.savetxt("file.csv", data1, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: I hope it's not gonna affect the file size converting them into string and storing them?

Comment: The file is a text file. Numpy implicitly converts all numbers to strings before writing them, anyway.

Comment: With `%s` you loose control over column width and decimal precision, the kinds of things that `%.2f` formats provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using pandas with `na_rep` parameter. For example:

```
df.to_csv(r'path\df.csv', sep=',', na_rep=np.NaN)
```