# numpy.set_printoptions(nanstr='') is not working for numpy.savetxt()

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python 3.6.4. I am running an experiment to find out a faster alternate to pandas.to_csv() and using numpy.savetxt() to store the dataframe as csv in a file. By default, this function puts `nan` string for np.nan values in the dataframe. I want to put '' (empty string) for np.nan values in the csv output.

I tried `np.set_printoptions(nanstr='')`, which doesn't seem to make any difference. I tried changing nanstr to various string values but looks like the option is not honored at all. I do see the option being set correctly in np.get_printoptions()

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1_node', '2_node', '3_node', '4_node'],
                    'prop1': [np.nan,np.nan,'ABC','DEF'],
                    'prop2': [1,np.nan,2,np.nan]})

print("Numpy version: {}".format(np.__version__))
np.set_printoptions(nanstr='')
print(np.get_printoptions())
np.savetxt( 'temp.op', df0.values, fmt="%s", comments='',delimiter=",")
```

Output:

```
Numpy version: 1.14.0
{'edgeitems': 3, 'threshold': 1000, 'floatmode': 'maxprec', 'precision': 8, 'suppress': False, 'linewidth': 75, 'nanstr': '', 'infstr': 'inf', 'sign': '-', 'formatter': None, 'legacy': False}

temp.op
1_node,nan,1.0
2_node,nan,nan
3_node,ABC,2.0
4_node,DEF,nan
```

Expected output:

```
1_node,,1.0
2_node,,
3_node,ABC,2.0
4_node,DEF,
```

Comment: From the documentation: 'These options determine the way floating point numbers, arrays and other NumPy objects are displayed.' I do not believe this influences in any way the way savetxt writes to files, unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Numpy Array with NaNs into CSV in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273886/writing-numpy-array-with-nans-into-csv-in-python)

Comment: `savetxt` uses python `%` formating. Look at its code.