# How to write an object typed array into csv file with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have two numpy arrays(A, B) and 2 scalar values(C,D) that I want to store in a csv file.
I know how to write a single numpy array in it:

```
A = np.array(...)
np.savetxt('path/to/file/filename.csv', A, delimiter = ",")
```

I want the first two columns of my csv-file to contain the 2 arrays A and B and then have the 2 scalar values C and D as the first entry of columns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use iterations or other libraries e.g. *Pandas* to do this, because each of the columns will have a different size (***in this example we will handle unequal sizes of A and B***). So the saved array must be specified as *object* type if you want to do this by `np.savetxt`. If you use *object* typed array to be saved by `np.savetxt`, it will just fill the first row of the *csv* file:

```
A = np.array([2, 4.1, 5], dtype=np.float64)
B = np.array([2, 7, 9, 1], dtype=np.float64)
C = 1
D = 7

Output = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=object)
Output[0, :] = A, B, C, D

np.savetxt('Output.csv', Output, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

which will be as:
[image]

I don't think if it can be good handled just by NumPy, and will be better to try by other libraries such as Pandas or … or use iterations to open the *csv* file and import in it. But if you want to use NumPy for doing so (*just for figuring out how to do this work by NumPy*), it can be achieved by padding to equalize the arrays' sizes in indirect way. For this aim, we must find maximum length of the `A` and `B` to pad the arrays to that length. I filled the padded indices by `np.nan` in this example and then [removed it for the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273913/13394817):

```
max_len = max(A.shape[0], B.shape[0])

A_pad = np.pad(A, (0, max_len - A.shape[0]), constant_values=(np.nan,))
B_pad = np.pad(B, (0, max_len - B.shape[0]), constant_values=(np.nan,))
C_pad = np.pad(np.array([C], dtype=np.float64), (0, max_len - 1), constant_values=(np.nan,))
D_pad = np.pad(np.array([D], dtype=np.float64), (0, max_len - 1), constant_values=(np.nan,))

Output = np.array([A_pad, B_pad, C_pad, D_pad]).T
Output = Output.astype(str)
Output[Output == 'nan'] = ''

np.savetxt('Output.csv', Output, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

[image]

Comment: while i appreciate the solution, pushing array into pandas much more easy, and by default, according to the pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html , to_csv handles missing data repr.( nan values ) for you. Please check my solution.

Comment: @UtkuCan, (+1) I mentioned that Pandas and iteration will be easier to use. **But**, as it is written in the title of the question by OP, it asked for a NumPy. So I showed how to do this by NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

Since csv files are comma seperated values, terminology of column is more useful with excel files. If I understand correctly, you want your data shape like this

```
A1 B1 C D 
A2 B2  
A3 B3
.  .
.  .
.  .
```

It is very useful to change arrays to pandas dataframe and save whatever you like (excel or csv) . If we go back your question, solution could be like this:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
C = [5]
D = [6]


_array = [A,B,C,D] #all values into list

data = pd.DataFrame(_array).T  # in order to get what you want, you have to transpose dataframe

data.to_csv('/Users/../data.csv',index=False,header=False)  # save as csv file

data.to_excel('/Users/../data.xlsx',index=False,header=False) # save as excel file to get column based
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the arrays first, maybe using `zip_longest`:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
import numpy as np

A = np.array(...)  # 1d arrays
B = np.array(...)
C = 1.0  # scalars
D = 2.0
with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip_longest(A, B, [C], [D], fillvalue=''):
        w.writerow(row)
```

If A and B are long, you will get lots of blank cells at the end of each row, which could be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all A and B are of the same length. I would use pandas to organise it the way I want then do `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`
I would do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = B = np.arange(5)  # 1d arrays
C = 1.0  # scalars
D = 2.0

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': np.NaN, 'D': np.NaN})
df.loc[0, 'C'] = C     # change 0 to 1 to fill the next row 
df.loc[0, 'D'] = D     # change 0 to 1 to fill the next row
df.to_csv('path/to/file/filename.csv')
```